# Is there a way to use the current session credential when attempting authenticated web requests in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

In Powershell (and by extension, .NET) it is possible to use the default session credential for authentication with various commands. For example, in regards to web requests I can do the following from Powershell:

```
# Make request using default session credentials
Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials https://privateapi.someserver.tld
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in Ruby (perhaps with the help of a gem), so I can make use of the current session credentials for web requests from within the context of Ruby as opposed to shelling out to Powershell for this? What I want to do is have a Chef library function that pulls information from a REST API during the compile phase of a `chef-client` run, but don't want the user providing their credentials via attributes, and for the set of recipes I'm looking to use this in, Chef Vault is not a viable solution to store credentials.

Currently I am doing the following on the Ruby side which works, but would like to keep the code in Ruby if at all possible:

```
ps_json = `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials 'https://server.domain.tld/inventory?fqdn=#{node['name']}' | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100`
resp_obj = JSON.parse ps_json
```